# flex-box how to make more responsive "boxes"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want for the boxes to be more responsive, and to keep 1:1 ratio all the time.
When I set min-width to the .box1, .box2 they always take the whole width of the .box ! And it is like they don't respond to height?

I don't want to boxes be full width (or height) of the flex items, since i want some space between them, and I don't want them to overflow their .box container,..( I want keep them inside)

I know I can use media queries to resize the .box1,.box2,.box3, .. but is there any other way?

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  //margin:0 -40px;
}


/*first two children*/

.grid>.box:not(:last-child) {
  background: grey;
  width: 50%;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3 {
  border: 2px solid #111;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  text-align: center;
}

.box1,
.box2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box p {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box1">
        <p>Here is something !</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box ">
      <div class="box2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box ">
      <div class="box3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get your complete query but if you want to make square responsive without adjusting its height manually then use padding hack

```
.box1,
.box2,
.box3{
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 50%;
        postition:relative
        background: red;
    }
```

Comment: I tired to use padding, but how will I keep the items appart? Since then item will fill up the whole box. Do I use negative margins? But the main problem with padding is that my boxes keep oveflowing their container when rotated and giving me horozontal scroll.